# What is "ci" in "concentrarci"?

Tags: grammar

> Trovare stabilità in ciò che conosciamo e amiamo, e **concentrarci** sulle cose che danno significato e scopo alla vita.

What does "ci" mean in "concentrarci"? I could not find an explanation in Italian courses.

Comment: Look for _riflessivo_, both in other questions here and in your grammar books.

Comment: hi i did, i only find in riflessivo in ci concentriamo ,but i will look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The English verb "concentrate", in its meaning of "focus", requires in Italian the reflexive form of *[concentrare](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/concentrare/)*.

Italian reflexive pronouns (*mi*, *ti*, *si*, *ci*, *vi*) [can be attached at the end of the infinitive forms](https://learnitalian.web.unc.edu/home/verbs/reflexives-and-reciprocals/):

- *concentrare* + ***mi*** = *concentrar**mi***
- *concentrare* + ***si*** = *concentrar**si***

| Italian | Literal translation | English |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ***Mi** concentro su qualcosa* | *I concentrate **myself** on something | I concentrate on something |
| ***Ti** concentri su qualcosa* | *You concentrate **yourself** on something | You concentrate on something |
| ***Ci** dobbiamo concentrare* | *We have to concentrate **ourselves** | We have to concentrate |
| *Concentrar**ci** sulle cose che danno significato alla vita* | *Concentrating **ourselves** on things that give meaning to life | Concentrating on things that make [our] life meaningful |

NB: "To concentrate on things that make life meaningful" can also be translated as

- *Concentrar**mi** sulle cose che danno significato alla vita*, if I'm talking about myself,
- *Concentrar**ti***, if I'm talking about you (singular),
- *Concentrar**vi***, if I'm talking about you (plural),
- *Concentrar**si***, if I'm talking about him / her / in general.